# sort json facebook data

Tags: facebook, json, sorting

i'm trying to figure out how to sort the json data provided by a facebook events feed.

This is the code I've been using

```
                $int_count = 1;
                $FBpage = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/demo/events?access_token=170978966368624|vNXbO1MPwpvP56jU6zWGCyRESQ');
                $FBdata = json_decode($FBpage);
                foreach ($FBdata->data as $events )
                    {
                $x_sdt = explode("T",$events->start_time);
                $x_sd = explode("-",$x_sdt[0]);
                if($x_sdt[0] > date("Y-m-d"))
                    { 
                $StatusID = explode("_", $events->id);
                    echo '<ul class="shows">';
                    echo '<li class="date">';
                        echo $x_sd[2]."/".$x_sd[1]."/".$x_sd[0];
                    echo '</li>';
                    echo '<li class="title"><a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/shows/#'.$events->id.'">'.maxTruncate($events->name, 62).'</a></li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    }
                $int_count++;
                if($int_count==5){ break; }

                    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, so far I beleive i should be using usort(), but when I look at tutorials i've got no idea what the go is. any bombs of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `usort`, you just have to write your own little comparison function, that gets two of the arrays elements as parameters, compares them by whatever metric you like, and returns a value saying which one is supposed to be considered “greater” than the other.

Have a look at the examples in the PHP manual, it’s really quite easy.

If you still can’t get it to work on your own, then please describe what you tried and on what (example) data structure.

Comment: It worked, thanks. for anyone looking to get this done, its very helpful to convert the timestamp facebook provides to a unix timestamp, then run through a comparison function.